# Possible Bug with Get Team Method of Microsoft Teams Group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I think this is a bug, but looking for feedback from Microsoft Teams people.  Using the new REST API to [get the Team for a Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_get).

What I find is that if I have only the `Groups.Read.All` permission, it fails with an "Unauthorized" error.  However, if I change my permissions to `Groups.ReadWrite.All` then it works.

I'm just doing a GET, so I don't understand why I need to have the Write permission.  We're always trying to do things with Least Privileged Access so would like to avoid it.  Is it possible that this is just a bug in the preview, or should we expect this requirement to continue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a bug. It should work exactly as you expect.

We have filed a bug and will fix it shortly. No ETA yet.

Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Fix should be deployed next week.